# SSH paramiko Azure

Tags: python, linux, azure, ssh, paramiko

I have usually no problems ssh'ing in python with paramiko (version paramiko==1.15.3). Doing:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('mylinodebox.com', key_filename='key_filename='/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_linode', port=2222)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

works absolutely fine for me for this linode machine. But for another, Azure, machine if I try the same only replacing the connect line with

```
ssh.connect('myazurebox.net', key_filename='/home/me/.ssh/the-azure-ssh.key', port=22)
```

I get

```
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

This is despite the fact that from the linux terminal I have no issues at all ssh'ing into the Azure machine with the keyfile ( I do `ssh myazurebox` and have the ssh config below), so I know the creds are good.

My ssh config file looks like

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ServerAliveInterval 15
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto

Host myazurebox
   HostName myazurebox.net
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/the-azure-ssh.key
   User <azureuser>

Host mylinodebox
    HostName mylinodebox.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_linode 
    Port 2222
```

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working?

Adding the line `paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)` after the import doesn't show much more:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group14-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for myazurebox.net: 8d596885f13b8e45c1edd7d94bbfa817
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key d403d1c6bec787e486548a3e0fbfa373
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key 12e9db4c2cd2be32193s78b0b13cb5eb
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key 1906e3debc819c0f5f40080d43de587d
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I examined the logs on the server at `/var/log/auth.log` after setting `LogLevel DEBUG` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. It turned out that paramiko was trying keys with fingerprints from my local [ssh-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) (which can be listed by doing `ssh-add -l) by not actually trying the keyfile I provided in the arguments to ssh.connect. Openssh via the terminal also tried the keys from ssh-agent by then finally tried the keyfile.

I added the azure keyfile to the ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add /home/lee/.ssh/the-azure-ssh.key
```

and ran the script above again. This time paramiko established the connection successfully.

(Does anyone know why adding the key to the agent works with paramiko but not the keyfile alone?)

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed.

I reviewed the doc of Python package `paramiko` and writed my simple code as below. It works for Azure Linux VM(Ubuntu 1404 LTS). My local OS is Ubuntu.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('<my_vm_name>.cloudapp.net', 22, '<username>', '<password>')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: You're not using keys

Comment: @fpghost Thanks for your answer! I reproduce the issue, and your answer is the only one work solution for using keyfile by now.